# Ebay motors api - Category is not valid. ID 33562

Tags: ebay-api

Trying to post the item in ebay motors using ebay api call - AddItem. It throws me an error saying as below.  Could you please show some light on this.

Note - I am able to add the item manually in ebay motors with compatability. I fetched the item details (which is added manually) using the api call - GetItem. Placed the same details in the AddItem api call. Though it got failed with below error.

```
<ShortMessage>Category is not valid.</ShortMessage>
<LongMessage>The category is not valid, select another category.</LongMessage>
<ErrorCode>107</ErrorCode>
<SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
<ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
```

Request message is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AddItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
   <RequesterCredentials>
      <eBayAuthToken>********PG1QKFIlH****</eBayAuthToken>
   </RequesterCredentials>
   <Version>967</Version>
   <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
   <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
    <Item>
        <Title>Sample ebay motor brake fitment product</Title>
        <Description>Hummer Truck Right Side Mirror</Description>
        <StartPrice currencyID="USD">236.0</StartPrice>
        <Country>US</Country>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>
        <Location>Los Angeles, California</Location>
        <DispatchTimeMax>2</DispatchTimeMax>
        <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
        <PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>
        <PayPalEmailAddress>w*****1@gmail.com</PayPalEmailAddress>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <PrimaryCategory>
            <CategoryID>33562</CategoryID>
        </PrimaryCategory>
        <PictureDetails>
            <GalleryType>Gallery</GalleryType>
            <GalleryURL>http://****/z/QJsAAOSwXSJXPHk~/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F</GalleryURL>
            <PhotoDisplay>PicturePack</PhotoDisplay>
            <PictureURL>http://*****/z/QJsAAOSwXSJXPHk~/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F</PictureURL>
        </PictureDetails>
        <ShippingDetails>
            <ApplyShippingDiscount>false</ApplyShippingDiscount>
            <GlobalShipping>true</GlobalShipping>
            <CalculatedShippingRate>
                <WeightMajor measurementSystem="English" unit="lbs">0</WeightMajor>
                <WeightMinor measurementSystem="English" unit="oz">0</WeightMinor>
            </CalculatedShippingRate>

            <ShippingServiceOptions>
                <ShippingService>ShippingMethodStandard</ShippingService>
                <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceCost>
                <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
                <ExpeditedService>false</ExpeditedService>
                <ShippingTimeMin>1</ShippingTimeMin>
                <ShippingTimeMax>6</ShippingTimeMax>
                <FreeShipping>true</FreeShipping>
            </ShippingServiceOptions>
            <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
            <ThirdPartyCheckout>false</ThirdPartyCheckout>
            <TaxTable>
                <TaxJurisdiction>
                    <JurisdictionID>CA</JurisdictionID>
                    <SalesTaxPercent>10.0</SalesTaxPercent>
                    <ShippingIncludedInTax>false</ShippingIncludedInTax>
                </TaxJurisdiction>
            </TaxTable>
            <ShippingDiscountProfileID>0</ShippingDiscountProfileID>
            <InternationalShippingDiscountProfileID>0</InternationalShippingDiscountProfileID>
            <ExcludeShipToLocation>Alaska/Hawaii</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <ExcludeShipToLocation>US Protectorates</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <ExcludeShipToLocation>APO/FPO</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <ExcludeShipToLocation>Africa</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <ExcludeShipToLocation>Asia</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <ExcludeShipToLocation>Central America and Caribbean</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <ExcludeShipToLocation>Europe</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <ExcludeShipToLocation>Middle East</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <ExcludeShipToLocation>Oceania</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <ExcludeShipToLocation>Southeast Asia</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <ExcludeShipToLocation>South America</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <ExcludeShipToLocation>BM</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <ExcludeShipToLocation>GL</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <ExcludeShipToLocation>MX</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <ExcludeShipToLocation>PM</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <ExcludeShipToLocation>PO Box</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <SellerExcludeShipToLocationsPreference>true</SellerExcludeShipToLocationsPreference>
        </ShippingDetails>

        <ReturnPolicy>
            <RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>
            <Refund>Money Back</Refund>
            <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_14</ReturnsWithinOption>
            <ReturnsWithin>14 Days</ReturnsWithin>
            <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
            <ReturnsAccepted>Returns Accepted</ReturnsAccepted>
            <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
            <ShippingCostPaidBy>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidBy>
            <RestockingFeeValue>No</RestockingFeeValue>
            <RestockingFeeValueOption>NoRestockingFee</RestockingFeeValueOption>
        </ReturnPolicy>
        <ItemCompatibilityList>
            <Compatibility>
                <NameValueList/>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Year</Name>
                    <Value>2008</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Make</Name>
                    <Value>Workhorse Custom Chassis</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Model</Name>
                    <Value>R26</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Trim</Name>
                    <Value>Base Motor Home - Stripped Chassis</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Engine</Name>
                    <Value>8.1L 496Cu. In. V8 GAS OHV Naturally Aspirated</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <CompatibilityNotes></CompatibilityNotes>
            </Compatibility>
            <Compatibility>
                <NameValueList/>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Year</Name>
                    <Value>1998</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Make</Name>
                    <Value>Advance Mixer</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Model</Name>
                    <Value>M</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Trim</Name>
                    <Value>Base Straight Truck - Half Cab</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Engine</Name>
                    <Value>-- DIESEL</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <CompatibilityNotes></CompatibilityNotes>
            </Compatibility>
            <Compatibility>
                <NameValueList/>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Year</Name>
                    <Value>1988</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Make</Name>
                    <Value>Yugo</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Model</Name>
                    <Value>GVS</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Trim</Name>
                    <Value>Base Hatchback 3-Door</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Engine</Name>
                    <Value>1.1L 1116CC l4 GAS SOHC Naturally Aspirated</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <CompatibilityNotes></CompatibilityNotes>
            </Compatibility>
            <Compatibility>
                <NameValueList/>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Year</Name>
                    <Value>1963</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Make</Name>
                    <Value>Wolseley</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Model</Name>
                    <Value>1500</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Trim</Name>
                    <Value>Base</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Engine</Name>
                    <Value>1.5L 1489CC 91Cu. In. l4 GAS OHV Naturally Aspirated</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <CompatibilityNotes></CompatibilityNotes>
            </Compatibility>
            <Compatibility>
                <NameValueList/>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Year</Name>
                    <Value>1928</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Make</Name>
                    <Value>Yellow Cab</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Model</Name>
                    <Value>Model D-1</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Trim</Name>
                    <Value>Base</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Engine</Name>
                    <Value>--</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <CompatibilityNotes></CompatibilityNotes>
            </Compatibility>
        </ItemCompatibilityList>

    </Item>
</AddItemRequest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you using the `100` as the value of the HTTP header `X-EBAY-API-SITEID`. This ensures that your request is routed to the eBay motors site where the category is valid. Using `0` in the header routes the request to ebay.com where the category is not valid.